# How to retrieve specific value from XML document in Windows Phone

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

How to get specified value from XML document.
Here is my XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Id>22608</Id>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
    </row>
<root>
```

How do I get the "Name" node value that is "ABC".

Comment: There's quite a few ways to do that depending on your requirements. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use XDocument/XElement

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
  <root>
     <row>
       <Id>22608</Id>
       <Name>ABC</Name>
  </row>
<root>");
var nameElement = doc.Root.Element("row").Element("Name");
```

as a side note you should stick to a naming convention. Either start all elements with a captal letter or use all lower letters but I'd recommend not mixing as in your example. If you have a naming convention you only need to remember the name of the element and not the casing too. Since the names are not checked until run-time having a consistent naming convention will save you a lot of debugging in the long run